# Rendering Kendo Coumn dynamically

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Columns are rendering dynamically according to response from server. And column names are configured by user, which can be anything.

On rendering Grid it is giving below warning in console. Column name coming from server is 'Total Seen'

> Grid column field name 'Total Seen' does not look like a valid JavaScript identifier. Identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters (including "$" or "_"), and may not start with a digit. Please use only valid identifier names to ensure error-free operation.

Can anyone help?

Comment: is it because there is a space inbetween?

Comment: Yes but I cant remove space. So is there any way to avoid these warnings? @Keith

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar problem recently, but it was connected with other language symbols (Russian).

Here is [StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-ui-grid-aq4ztx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) I made for you to show available workaround (it's based on official Kendo UI Grid docs). Look at `Product Name` field in my example.

The main idea is that you set your columns' fields to appropriate values, ie valid Javascript identifiers, before rendering grid. But `title` property will still contain user's value.

Method `_prepareColumnFields` is used to convert column's field to valid identifier via regex check (be aware, that for simplicity I use `\W` regex, but is does not include `$` symbol which is also a valid one).

Method `_getProcessedGridData` is used to prepare dataset, ie replacing invalid property names, which are stored in `_fieldsMapping` object

In general, I would say that this solution is a little bit messy. I would advise you to prepare proper column names on the user's input stage.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But what if my data set is large in size?

Comment: Do you have control over initial column configuring by user? If yes, then you just need to apply the same kind of method like `_prepareColumnFields` on that stage to prevent any future possible difficulties. Other option is to apply this processing on the server side.

If you don't have that control, you can only preprocess data on the fly like I described in my example. In case of big datasets you should use grid pagination to prevent long running rendering.

Comment: @khush why did you unaccept the answer? any difficulties occurred?

Comment: Yes, this answer helped me to show the data but whenever I perform any action, renamed keys are send instead of actual keys which was causing me the issues, so it didnt solve my issue

Comment: What do you mean by "any action"? If you want me to help, please, elaborate more on this. Reproducing this issue in my stackblitz wil make it clear

Comment: There are many actions on click of a column in my grid. One of them is, on click of a column, dialog is opened which uses the values from the selected column and calls an API.